# Is this real continuous function on $[a,b]$ increasing?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, monotone-functions

Let $f$ be a real continuous function on a bounded interval $[a,b]$ such that every point $x$ in $[a,b)$ has a positive number $\delta$ where every point $t$ in $(x,x+\delta)$ satisfies $f(t)>f(x)$. Is $f$ increasing on $[a,b]$? (This question comes from trying to understand Rudin's proof of Theorem 7.21 in *Real and Complex Analysis*).

It's enough to show that $f$ is locally increasing, but this seems tricky. I feel that there might be transfinite induction involved, but I don't know much about this topic.

Comment: Yes it is increasing in $[a, b] $. Result fails if $f$ is not continuous. Note that the hypotheses of the results are stated by saying that $f $ is strictly increasing on the right at every point of $ [a, b) $. You can define increasing on left at a point in similar manner. If a function is increasing both and left and right of a point we say it is increasing at that point. You can prove that if a function is increasing at every point of some interval then it is increasing in the interval (and we don't need continuity).

Comment: I figured it fails without continuity but I don't see why it is true with continuity @ParamanandSingh

Comment: See my previous updated comment. Also when the function is increasing in one direction (say right) at every point then we also need continuity to prove the increasing nature in whole interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that it is not increasing. Then $f(x)>f(y)$ for some $x,y\in[a,b]$ such that $x<y$. Let $z\in[x,y]$ be such that $f(z)=\max f([x,y])$. Then $z<y$. Now apply your hypothesis to the point $z$.

Comment: I think the stronger result $x<y\Rightarrow f(x) <f(y) $ holds and your approach only establishes $f(x) \leq f(y) $.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Once you know it is weakly increasing, applying the property in the hypothesis once more shows that it must be strongly increasing.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: yeah got it! I was somewhat quick in posting my comment.